# Storing a C++20 function-like object from a forwarding reference?

Tags: c++, c++20

In C++20, let's suppose I want to `std::make_unique` a copy (or move as appropriate) and store a function-like object that is passed in a forwarding reference...

```
template<typename F>
std::unique_ptr<???> make_copy_of_functor(F&& f) {
    return std::make_unique<???>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

What goes in the `???`s ?  Is it correct to just put `F` there...

```
template<typename F>
std::unique_ptr<F> make_copy_of_functor(F&& f) {
    return std::make_unique<F>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

or do I need to decay it in some fashion?  (I'm possibly confused about the reference collapsing rules around forwarding references.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As forwarding reference, when being passed lvalue `F` would be deduced as lvalue-reference, you can use [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) to remove reference part (and add pointer for function type).

```
template<typename F>
auto make_copy_of_functor(F&& f) {
    return std::make_unique<std::decay_t<F>>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

Comment: Actually I get `error: new cannot be applied to a function type` when used on a normal function,  I guess the forwarding reference is taking a reference to the function, and not applying the function-to-pointer standard conversion.  If I use make_copy_of_functor(&my_function) it works.

Comment: Maybe `std::decay` is better?  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay   Not sure.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Yes, we need to make `F` to be function pointer type explicitly; `make_copy_of_functor(&my_function)` does that. And yes, `std::decay` seems better.

Comment: Yes, if we use `std::decay` then `make_copy_of_functor(my_function)` works (without `&`).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass by value and then move into a new object:

```
template <typename F>
auto make_copy_of_functor(F f) {
  return std::make_unique<F>(std::move(f));
}
```

Comment: Won't this double move compared to other solution?  One move into the function parameter and then another move into the constructor?  Or is one of them elided?

Comment: Yes. If you pass by rvalue, this will invoke two move operations, else will invoke one copy operation and one move. But the move operation is cheap and this code looks tidier (which may less fallible).